# Android: Intent (Context packageContext, Class<?> cls) use inner class?

Tags: android, class, android-intent

For

`public Intent (Context packageContext, Class <> cls)`

How do I set the Class to access an inner class?
Usually I do:

`new Intent(this, NAMEOFCLASS.class)`

But what if I want to use the inner class?

Will this work?

`new Intent(this, NAMEOFCLASS.class.INNERCLASS.class)`

The innerclass is a class that extends broadcast receiver. I want to create a pending intent that will send a broadcast to the inner class.

```
public class IntentServiceBroadcast extends IntentService {

private broadcastReceiver BroadcastReceiver = new broadcastReceiver();

private class broadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
  {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

    }
  }
```

Then use alarmManager to send a PendingIntent

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, IntentServiceBroadcast.BroadcastReceiver.class), 0);

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, getTime()
                .getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Not sure if the above code works.

Comment: what are trying to achieve? Also is your `INNERCLASS.class` a activity class?. To access an inner class why do you need intents

Comment: I think you need just `NAMEOFCLASS.INNERCLASS.class`

Comment: to send a pendingIntent so that the innerclass receives a broad cast

Comment: ok so NAMEOFCLASS.INNERCLASS.class I'll try that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

`new Intent(this, IntentServiceBroadcast.BroadcastReceiver.class)`

Use

`new Intent(ACTION)`

Register a receiver to listen and BAM!

Comment: What is your declaration of **ACTION**?

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't reply directly under your post, could you be a little more specific as to why you want to do that? Like, post some code up.

According to what I know, making an intent's second parameter something that does not extend Activity directly is a bit weird. When you do an intent, you need to pass its *Context* as a first parameter, and the name of the class you want that intent to change from the current context.

So I think inner classes aren't that appropriate in this case. So, could you enlighten us a bit with the situation?

Answer (score 0):

if your class is a kind of class that you can call `this` or `yourclassname.this` call that but if you cannot do this:

1)write this code under  `class ########## extends ##############` :

```
Context con;
```

2)and then write `con` instead of `this` or `yourclassname.this`

finished!

Comment: I am not having trouble with context. I can already access that. I want to know how to reference the inner class.

Comment: i think you have to just write yourinnerclassname.class and finished no need to write the NAMEOFCLASS.class.INNERCLASS.class